# modify the recipient address of an email on the file in the postfix queue

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have a few emails in my mailq which are bounced for a good reason, the email address is wrong. 
I was wondering if it is possible to modify the address of the recipient on the fly.
I can see the directory where the mail deferred are stored and I could probably change something there, but i am wondering if there is a proper way to do this.

Any thought?

Comment: As documented, direct manipulation of queue files is not supported.

Comment: @adaptr this is an answer, not a comment ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way (or the least intrusive way) would be to have an address rewrite for that recipient. From the [Postfix Address Rewriting](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic)

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

/etc/postfix/generic:
    his@localdomain.local       hisaccount@hisisp.example
```

Following this example, you could try:

```
cd /etc/postfix
```

Add to the `generic` file or create it with:

```
yourbadlyspelledname@destination.com        you_name@destination.com
```

and build the associated map:

```
sudo postmap generic
```

Add to `main.cf`:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

make Postfix load this configuration change:

```
sudo postfix reload
```

`smtpd` will use `generic` to rewrite the problematic address upon next scan of queue.

Comment: Since smtp_generic_maps is applied to mail *delivery*, there is no need to re-queue the mail. The smtp(8) daemon performs this rewrite.

Comment: Good one, and don't forget to issue `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` after editing `/etc/postfix/generic`.

Comment: I integrated the 2 relevant commants from adaptr & kasimir, after successfully testing on an address to change.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with the config executables `postconf` or `postmap`?